# react-cache-buster always says There is no new version

Tags: reactjs, browser-cache

Followed the simple instructions for react-cache-buster. The build generates a meta.json file with the version number in the root. I have my app wrapped in the CacheBuster provider as instructed. All seems correct. To test I started with version 0.1.0, deployed, then bumped to 0.1.2 and deployed. Yet when I load the site it always says 'There is no new version. No cache refresh needed.' I have not tried the manual check yet, will do that next. What else do I need to do to have it detect a version change and reload on startup?

```
export const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <CacheBuster
        currentVersion={version}
        isEnabled={true}
        isVerboseMode={true}
      >
      <RouterProvider 
        router={router}
      />
      </CacheBuster>
    </>
  );
```

Comment: The claim that fetch(getMetaFileDirectory() + "/meta.json")) does not pull from cached results seems to be incorrect and will negate this entire concept. I added a console.log to checkCacheStatus and found the fetched metaVersion is the old version until I do a browser refresh. This defeats the purpose.

Comment: I was able to fix this with a simple update to add a timestamp to the fetch.  fetch(getMetaFileDirectory() + "/meta.json?ver=" + Date.now())

Answer (score 1):

Use a fetch Interceptor to attach a timestamp to your url, like

```
request: function(url, config) {
  if (url === "/meta.json") {
    url = `${url}?ver=${Date.now()})`;
  }
  return [url, config];
},
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch-intercept